# Obfuscating code in AutoIt3

Tags: obfuscation, autoit, deobfuscation

Some1 know which obfuscator obfuscate variables like this?

```
$a3a83605e4a
```

And functions like this?

```
Func a2060102a0b($a0c9b315f62, $a199bf1090b = 0, $a58ab015626 = False)
If NOT IsDeclared("SSA2060102A0B") Then
    Global $a40ab115d31 = a2a0000482b($os[3999]), $a4fab210961 = a2a0000482b($os[4000]), $a09ab311939 = a2a0000482b($os[4001]), $a25ab415f29 = a2a0000482b($os[4002]), $a53ab510350 = a2a0000482b($os[4003]), $a06ab61560c = a2a0000482b($os[4004]), $a57ab714857 = a2a0000482b($os[4005]), $a2dab81175c = a2a0000482b($os[4006]), $a0aab91562a = a2a0000482b($os[4007]), $a26aba10a40 = a2a0000482b($os[4008]), $a31abb11452 = a2a0000482b($os[4009]), $a19abc1013c = a2a0000482b($os[4010]), $a46abd1244d = a2a0000482b($os[4011]), $a61abe16335 = a2a0000482b($os[4012]), $a02abf1395e = a2a0000482b($os[4013])
    Global $ssa2060102a0b = 1
EndIf
If $a199bf1090b = Number($a40ab115d31) Then $a199bf1090b = a05a0d0391a()
If @error Then Return SetError(Number($a4fab210961), @extended, Number($a09ab311939))
Local $a49f0d12024 = DllCall($a25ab415f29, $a53ab510350, $a06ab61560c, $a57ab714857, $a199bf1090b, $a2dab81175c, $a0c9b315f62, $a0aab91562a, $a58ab015626, $a26aba10a40, Number($a31abb11452))
If @error OR NOT $a49f0d12024[Number($a19abc1013c)] Then Return SetError(Number($a46abd1244d), @extended, Number($a61abe16335))
Return $a49f0d12024[Number($a02abf1395e)]
EndFunc
```

Comment: That's easy to write it yourself, right? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Until recently, the full version of the SciTE editor was shipped with an obfuscator, which with correct flags would just change variable names (though by default does much more). This has since changed to a "stripper" which performs a similar function, but for the primary purpose of making scripts smaller as opposed to difficult to read.

Au3Stripper is available for download [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/) (scroll to the bottom of the page for the standalone version)

You may be able to find previous versions of the Obfuscator online (there is no official page for downloading old versions as far as I know).

There are some alternatives, such as one on the German forums [here](https://autoit.de/index.php/Thread/35572-Shadows-Open-Source-Obfuscator-in-C-C-f%C3%BCr-AutoIt/), though I haven't used it so can't say how good it is, or if the output matches what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It might be AutoIt Obfuscator from https://www.pelock.com/products/autoit-obfuscator

It seems it's using similar obfuscation techniques.